# How to retrieve articles from dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I've recently dived in the world of semantic web. It's been smooth, until now.
To the point... I'm trying to get Articles from dbpedia, but I don't get results somehow. For what I have seen in the DBpedia ontology, I think this is supposed to be correct. Article is a "subclass" of WrittenWork, so is Book. I can get books and their info through the rdf triples. When using a SPARQL query that is almost the same as the one for books, I don't get results. This is weird, because I know there are references to articles in Wikipedia.

The query for books:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?book
WHERE { ?book a dbo:Book . }
```

If I substitute dbo:Book for dbo:Article, I get nothing. I'm testing here: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Can someone point me the right direction?

Comment: What is your namespace definition for the prefix `dbo:`?

Comment: Do you know any resource in DBpedia which is an article?

Comment: @scotthenninger it's one of the default prefixes that you can see in http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov not in DBpedia, but I found more than one page in wikipedia that I think should be classified as such, and using the query you wrote in your answer I can confirm it has none.

Comment: @DanielMendonça an article should be a topic of a Wikipedia page to be classified as such. And if you have such an example, please share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you test which subslasses of `dbo:WrittenWork` have no members, using this query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE { 
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf dbo:WrittenWork .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?s a ?class }
}
```

you'll see that `dbo:Article` is among them.

Comment: You're right. I don't know how though. I have found some articles in Wikipedia, where dbpedia should get information.

Comment: Whoa.  That seems like a really inefficient way of saying `SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE { ?class rdfs:subClassOf dbo:WrittenWork .}` and doesn't get any instances of dbo:Article, which seems to be the OP's question.

Comment: @scotthenninger as `dbo:Book` and `dbo:Play` have members, and doubting that I know the correct URI of `dbo:Article`, my intention was to see which other subclasses of `dbo:WrittenWork` have no members. The query reflects that intention. In general, I prefer to have a query which gives some results, as n many case no results can be due to a malformed query.